# Can I use NER to detect specific information in text?

Tags: nlp

I'm working on a application and I need to create a NLP model to detect specific information in a piece of text. For example, let's take the following two pieces of text:

1. John teaches Operational Systems.
2. The product price will be adjusted 70% by the parameter A and 30% by the parameter B.

In example 1 I need a model to be able to detect Operational System as a topic. I guess a simple NER is able to do the job. In the example 2 I need to detect the combination of parameter A and 70% (parameter A, 70%) and parameter B and 30% (parameter B, 30%). Is NER able to be trained to accomplish this job? Can I train NER to return combination of different terms? There are better techniques to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could also try a **zero-shot classification**, but for that you have to assume the possible topics of your text. If you have no a priori idea about it, yes maybe a NER tagger (properly trained) could do the job
2. Have you considered a **Question Answering bot**? Basically it is a system that can answer to questions in natural language. Look at the example [here](https://huggingface.co/deepset/roberta-base-squad2?context=The+product+price+will+be+adjusted+70%25+by+the+parameter+A+and+30%25+by+the+parameter+B&question=How+much+the+price+will+be+adjusted+by+parameter+A%3F) and try it with your custom context-question:

- Context: `The product price will be adjusted 70% by the parameter A and 30% by the parameter B`
- Question: `How much the price will be adjusted by parameter A?`
- Answer: `70%` (with probability score `0.973`)

It's a different approach from what you suggested but I thaink that it could work

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, SilentCloud. About NER, how can I train a model that can perform the pairing of information? Like connecting 70% with parameter A.

Comment: That is Relation Extraction. I'm not an expert in that field, but I guess that if you Google it you will find a lot of material.